# Not able to solve import on com.google.appengine.tools.cloudstorage.GcsFilename Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage

I am trying to serve a blob , which take objects from GCS and serve it . In my servlet I need to import:

import com.google.appengine.tools.cloudstorage.GcsFileOptions;

import com.google.appengine.tools.cloudstorage.GcsFilename

I have downloaded Cloud Storage API from this link: https://code.google.com/p/google-api-java-client/wiki/APIs#Cloud_Storage_API

But somehow I am not able to compile my servlet. What am I missing here!!..Can anyone please tell me the steps on how to add this library in web application in Eclipse?

Code which I need to compile:

```
     private GcsFilename getFileName(HttpServletRequest req) {
                  String[] splits = req.getRequestURI().split("/", 4);
                  if (!splits[0].equals("") || !splits[1].equals("gcs")) {
                  throw new IllegalArgumentException("The URL is not formed as expected. " +
                  "Expecting /gcs/<bucket>/<object>");
                }
            return new GcsFilename(splits[2], splits[3]);
       }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the import is not in any of those jar files but this might help to download the library 
https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/googlecloudstorageclient/migrate

Comment: Thanks a Lot!!..I don't know if I read the information wrong or they don't have appropriate doc for the same. Thanks again!!

Comment: Could you please help me in this issue as well . I am using this code to list objects on GCS and I am not able to compile it.. link:https://developers.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1/objects/list             Storage.Objects.List listObjects = storage.objects().list("mybucket");
Objects objects;
do {
  objects = listObjects.execute();
  for (StorageObject object : objects.getItems()) {
    // Do things!
  }
  listObjects.setPageToken(objects.getNextPageToken());
} while (null != objects.getNextPageToken());

Comment: The error is on " Storage.Objects.List " and other syntax..Basically its not able to find right jar or import

Comment: download this jar files should do it https://developers.google.com/google-apps/tasks/setup

Comment: @ Omid Aminiva ..I am going to try this link and will let you know..Thanks for reply..Means a lot!!

Comment: @ Omid Aminiva ..I tried the given link by you and after following each step carfully I was successfully able to compile my code..Thanks!!